How can i correct product catalog
I uploaded 12 products in category of dresses but in the store only 8 products are showing and when i refresh the page products change but number remains the same. How can i correct it?

Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront > Products per Page on Grid Default Value :  change from 8 to 12

Generally, magento show the product with pagination on the category page.
So kindly check there is pagination on bottom side on page, which give you options to go on next page.
If you want to change that default pagination options to show more product on category page, then you can do it from here.
Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront > Products per Page on Grid Default Value : 12,24,36
